# C++: Properly using the LoadImage and SetCursor functions

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to write a quick and simple C++ program that changes the cursor icon to a custom image from a directory. The Windows Dev Center seems to have [some fairly straightforward documentation on how to do this in C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646970(v=vs.85).aspx), from which I came up with this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //HINSTANCE hInst = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    HINSTANCE hInst = NULL;
    HCURSOR cursor = (HCURSOR)LoadImage(hInst, "Image.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP,
                     32, 32, LR_LOADFROMFILE); //Also tried LR_SHARED
    cout << "Initializing\n";
    Sleep(1500);
    SetCursor(cursor);
    //Also tried SetSystemCursor(cursor, 32512);
    cout << "Setting cursor\n";
    Sleep(1500);
    DestroyCursor(cursor);
    cout << "Restoring cursor\n";   
    Sleep(2000);
    return 0;
}
```

The program should change the cursor to the bitmap image, then change it back, then exit. The messages get printed when I run it, but the cursor doesn't change like it should. I'm not entirely sure whether my problem lies with the LoadImage function, with the SetCursor function, or with something else. I've tried various types of HINSTANCEs for the HINSTANCE parameter of the LoadImage function, I've tried different flags for the last argument for the LoadImage function, and I've also tried using the SetSystemCursor function instead of the SetCursor function.

All I want to do is change the mouse cursor image. It seems like this should be really simple, but it turns out to be more complicated than I thought. My intent is to export this code as a DLL to use with the Java Native Interface for a Java project I'm using since the JVM can't change the cursor outside of the program window.

I've searched all over the place and saw some slightly similar questions here, but none that properly addressed the issue I'm having. I have seen some people mention that I need to call the SetCursor function in response to a WM_SETCURSOR message, but I'm not quite sure what they mean (I don't have much C++ experience, so please bear with me). I hope you guys can help me. Thanks.

Comment: It is much more involved than that. MSDN page on [using cursors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648380(v=vs.85).aspx#_win32_Creating_a_Cursor) should point you in the right direction.

Comment: `LoadImage` needs a *.cur file, not bitmap. You can make a *.cur file in Visual Studio's resource editor. Here you have a console program. `WM_SETCURSOR` and `WNDCLASS/LoadCursor` are used in windows program which have WinMain entry point instead. The cursor is usually limited to the window. `SetSystemCursor` will change the cursor for the whole desktop, but it's not a good option because the user should do it from control panel. You might try `SetCapture`/`ReleaseCapture` in window program or your Java program if it has something similar. There is also drag & drop option...

Comment: The question I have is this: What is the reason you want to change the cursor outside your own window? Is it for drag+drop, or for something else? The solution may be different. As for your last paragraph, Windows uses a message passing design for its UI. `WM_` _something_ is a window message. See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927.aspx) for a overview about messages and what they are used for.

Comment: @theB My intent is not for drag-and-drop purposes but rather for the cursor to automatically change at specified intervals. Anyway, thanks for the info, I'll see if I get get somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

There appear to be a few issues with your code. You are trying to load a `.bmp`, however, [LoadCursorFromFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadcursorfromfilea) states

> The data in the file must be in either .CUR or .ANI format

Whilst this may not be strictly true for `LoadImage` as I have been able to load an `.ico` into a cursor, I don't think you can load a `.bmp`.

Try something like

```
const HCURSOR customCursor = static_cast<HCURSOR>(LoadImage(nullptr, L"Cursor.cur", IMAGE_CURSOR, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE));
```

Also, I believe `SetCursor` is only for working with C++ desktop applications with a window. However, you can use [SetSystemCursor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setsystemcursor) to replace system cursors.

```
#define OEMRESOURCE
#include <windows.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

void SetAllSystemCursorsToCursor(HCURSOR cursor)
{
    //Need to copy the cursor each time as SetSystemCursor consumes the cursor
    HCURSOR cursorCopy = CopyCursor(cursor);
    SetSystemCursor(cursorCopy, OCR_APPSTARTING);

    cursorCopy = CopyCursor(cursor);
    SetSystemCursor(cursorCopy, OCR_NORMAL);

    cursorCopy = CopyCursor(cursor);
    SetSystemCursor(cursorCopy, OCR_CROSS);

    cursorCopy = CopyCursor(cursor);
    SetSystemCursor(cursorCopy, OCR_HAND);

    cursorCopy = CopyCursor(cursor);
    SetSystemCursor(cursorCopy, OCR_IBEAM);

    cursorCopy = CopyCursor(cursor);
    SetSystemCursor(cursorCopy, OCR_NO);

    cursorCopy = CopyCursor(cursor);
    SetSystemCursor(cursorCopy, OCR_SIZEALL);

    cursorCopy = CopyCursor(cursor);
    SetSystemCursor(cursorCopy, OCR_SIZENESW);

    cursorCopy = CopyCursor(cursor);
    SetSystemCursor(cursorCopy, OCR_SIZENS);

    cursorCopy = CopyCursor(cursor);
    SetSystemCursor(cursorCopy, OCR_SIZENWSE);

    cursorCopy = CopyCursor(cursor);
    SetSystemCursor(cursorCopy, OCR_SIZEWE);

    cursorCopy = CopyCursor(cursor);
    SetSystemCursor(cursorCopy, OCR_UP);

    cursorCopy = CopyCursor(cursor);
    SetSystemCursor(cursorCopy, OCR_WAIT);
}

int main()
{
    //Load cursor
    const HCURSOR customCursor = LoadCursorFromFile(L"Cursor.cur");

    //Replace all system cursors with loaded cursor
    SetAllSystemCursorsToCursor(customCursor);

    //Sleep the current thread to allow the user to play with new cursor
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(5000));

    //Restore original system cursors
    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETCURSORS, 0, nullptr, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change the cursor on a console window. If you popped up a dialog instead, I think the cursor would change. I have never seen a cursor change on a console window in Windows.